# Unity Built-in shader, cutout + transparent

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, transparency, cut, out

Is it possible to have a shader which uses both, cutout and transparency?
I need a classic built-in shader that uses cutout. But I also need the "full-opaque" parts to be transparently manageable.

But I also need the "full-opaque" parts to be transparent and not affect the cutout.

Comment: It should be possible, but not necessarily with a single texture. You'd have your primary TextureA with its own alpha channel, and a secondary single-channel 'cutout' TextureB and blend the output alpha between 0 and TextureA.alpha using TextureB

Comment: You can also stack two unique materials ontop of each other with separate shaders.